# converting string date time using hive datefunction

Tags: hive

i have a DateTime below in string format and I want to convert using hive date function that will extract the date, hour and minutes

Convert ‘2010-11-01 16:30:15’ to 2010-11-01 16:30 in hive

please any suggestions will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use below syntax to extract date,hour and minutes.

```
   select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2010-11-01 16:30:15',"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
    +-------------------+--+
    |        _c0        |
    +-------------------+--+
    | 2010-11-01 16:30  |
    +-------------------+--+
```